# Mailer Error:Message body empty help Me to fix it

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hey Everyone i am trying to Send email from my account but shows error "Message Body Missing". Can anyone help me to fix it.

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();  
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'abc@gmail.com';                   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '123';               // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->setFrom('ajayggi000@gmail.com', 'Amit Agarwal');     
$mail->addReplyTo('ajayggi000@gmail.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addAddress('manjinder05@gmail.com', 'Josh Adams');
$mail->addAddress('ajayggi000@gmail.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addCC('maniinder05@gmail.com');
$mail->addBCC('ajayggi000@gmail.com');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;    
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'Hey';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
```

Comment: This may help you:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687325/phpmailer-unable-to-load-msghtml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687325/phpmailer-unable-to-load-msghtml)

Answer (score 0):

This line sets both `Body` and `AltBody`, so setting them beforehand is pointless:

```
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
```

If you're ending up with `Body` being empty, it means that this line is not working as you think. The most obvious thing is that it's failing to read your `contents.html` file, so you should test that the return value from your file_get_contents call contains what you expect - if it's not, you're simply setting the message body to `false`, which is going to appear blank, as you're seeing. Try this:

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('contents.html'));
```

If this doesn't show your expected content, check why - a wrong path or permissions are the obvious things to check.

Answer (score -1):

```
$mail->Body    = file_get_contents('contents.html');
```

change the body.

Comment: This does not do what the author wants - `msgHTML()` does more than setting the body.